# VS2013 Boost using NuGet

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have been trying for days to get boost to work with my Visual Studio 2013 Premium install. I tried it with a zip install, and now with NuGet. Both methods have gotten me to same point of a linker error.

The error: 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib'

I looked through the mailing list for boost and found someone posting of a similar issue, but that was from 2012 with boost_1_54_0 or something, so not relevant at all to VS2013 or  boost 1_58_0.

I've also looked at a few forum posts, including SO, but none of them have the same issue I'm having. Either that, or they simply have no replies.

I can't really discern any of the flags that the error show because this is my first time ever using anything other than STL libraries or my own headers.

Any and all help would be appreciated, let me know if there's any other additional info that would be helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suspect you installed the NuGet package named simply "boost". This seems to contain all the Boost headers, but no compiled libraries. That's fine if you're interested in using only the header-only Boost libraries (i.e. most of them).

What you really want is the package named "boost-vc120" (vc120 refers to VC++ 12.0, which is the VC++ version that ships with VS2013). This has all the libraries as well. You'll notice that it'll take a lot longer to install.

In either case, NuGet will take care of setting up all the necessary VC++ Directories settings. No further configuration is needed.

Comment: I just installed the boost-vc120 package and it seemed to work. I initially avoided it because I misread the description and thought i saw "Windows XP". I have both boost and the boost-vc120 packages on my current solution. Is that going to affect anything if i remove the regular boost?

Comment: @user3857017 - removing boost should have no effect, but if it does you can always remove boost-vc120 as well and then re-install it.

Comment: Alright. I just ask because boost is a pretty big package to just leave sitting there for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

The structure of Boost NuGet packages is [here](http://getboost.codeplex.com/releases/view/137465). You can use [boost-vc120](http://www.nuget.org/packages/boost-vc120/1.57.0) but it will download ALL boost libraries to your project. So if you want to save disk space, then use [boost](http://www.nuget.org/packages/boost/1.57.0) package which gives you header files, and specific binary packages. In your case, it's [boost_system-vc120](http://www.nuget.org/packages/boost_system-vc120/).

You can't remove boost package because binary packages, such as boost-vc120/boost_system-vc120, depend on it.

Comment: `boost-vc120` will download all boost libraries, but it will only link the libraries you actually use in your project. Boost takes advantage of the VC++ `#pragma comment(lib)` directive in its headers to specify which libraries need to be linked in.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file `libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib` exist on your hard drive?

If yes, did you add the .lib to the linker/input/Additional Dependencies?

[image]

Comment: I never thought to look there, just left to class but when I get back I'll check. I'm currently just using whatever NuGet sets and installs with boost.

Comment: The library file name doesn't need to be added to that list. On MSVC, the boost headers use `#pragma comment(lib, "...")` directives to specify the library names automatically. What's important is to add the *directory* containing all the boost `.lib` files to `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`.

Comment: I didn't manage to find the file, but I did get it working via the other boost package in the other reply. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

Go to following web page:

https://github.com/sergey-shandar/getboost

From there you find "NuGet Packages for Boost." with multiple links.

If you pick first link - you will get to boost-includes nuget-package
instructions. Basically you need to open Package manager in Visual studio, select correct project, and type command "Install-Package boost -Version 1.69.0" - it will enable
boost includes automatic downloading to "packages" folder.

By following other links you can get boost static libraries for your specific Visual studio - follow "boost-vc141" to get Visual studio 2017 static libraries.

That boost package will get a lot of boost libraries - if you don't need all of them - make temporary project, get boost static libraries, and copy paste libraries which you need by yourself.